# Different linear maps with the same Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Imagine I have the following matrix in Jordan form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
3&1&0\\
0&3&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
By defining this matrix to be a representation of a linear map in a basis $B$, we can imagine infinite number of linear maps being generated from this matrix, by choosing different $B$. Let us call two of them $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Now $T_1$ and $T_2$ will have almost identical properties (eigenvalues with the same multiplicities, characteristic equation, minimal polynomial), because they have the same canonical form. The only difference, I think, would be eigenvectors since this representation is in different bases.

Is that the only different? and how are all these linear maps related to each other? can we say that $T_1 = S^{-1}T_2S$ for some invertible linear map $S$?

Comment: Yes, similarity is an equivalence relation. Two matrices with the same Jordan form are each similar to the Jordan matrix, and hence are similar to one another.

Comment: I understand that. If I were talking about one linear map in two different bases, then they would have the same Jordan form and obviously similar to each other. But instead of talking about one linear map and two matrices, I'm talking about two linear maps having the same Jordan matrix in possibly different bases.

Comment: You're confusing yourself. These are different (similar) matrix representatives of one linear map.

Comment: Take these two linear maps. T1(x,y,z) = (3x+y,3y,2z) and T2(x,y,z) = (2x+y,-x+4y,2z). These are two different maps, yet they can be represented using the same Jordan matrix in the question. I don't know what that "one linear map" is that you are talking about.

Comment: You have two different matrices representing one linear map with respect to two different bases. Since you're witting everything in terms of the standard coordinates, you think you have different linear maps.